# Absolute positioning from border exterior

Tags: html, css

When I absolute-position an element inside a relative element, the coordinates are calculated from the edges of the container without taking into account the borders (what would be equivalent to positioning from the interior side of the border.)

Is there any way of positioning the element but from the exterior side of the border?

For example: if I have a red square (like the first one) without a border, the text sticks to the top left of the container because it has `top:0; left:0`. But the text in the second square still has `top:0;left:0`, but the border pushes the text inside the square:

```css
.box {
  position:relative;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
}

.box-bordered {
  border:25px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.text {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>

<div class="box box-bordered">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

What I would like for it is for the text to keep sticking to the top left corner of the colored area. Is that possible? How could it be done?

> Note: This is more of a theory question out of curiosity; I know there are alternatives that will work (at least visually) like using negative margins, negative positioning values or an inset `box-shadow`:
>
> ```css
> .box {
>   position:relative;
>   width:150px;
>   height:150px;
>   background:red;
>   box-sizing:border-box;
>   margin:10px;
>   float:left;
> }
>
> .box-shadow {
>   box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
> }
>
> .text {
>   position:absolute;
>   top:0;
>   left:0;
>   color:white;
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <div class="box box-shadow">
>   <div class="text">Text</div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> but what I would like to know if it it's possible doing while keeping the borders.

Comment: Keep in mind that borders can go inside only if the box-sizing: border-box; property is set.

Comment: It has `box-sizing: border-box` in both cases

Comment: If changing the html a bit doesn't bother you, you can have a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/87hurwnu/ Or even better without changing the html https://jsfiddle.net/87hurwnu/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No box shadow but not quite border either. How about this?

```css
.box {
  position:relative;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
}

.box:before {
  content:" ";
  border:25px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  height:100%;
  z-index:1;
  position:absolute;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:100%;
}

.text {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  color:white;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

or box-bordered:after  if you want to keep the class on the div element

Comment: This is a really simple and smart alternative. I like it

Answer (score 1):

The only two solutions that come to my mind are:

1. setting a negative margin equal to the border width on `.text`
2. using negative values on the top and left property.

```css
.box {
  position:relative;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
}

.box-bordered {
  border:25px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.text {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  color:white;
  margin: -25px;
}
.text2 {
  position:absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left:-25px;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box-bordered">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>

<div class="box box-bordered">
  <div class="text2">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a generic solution that doesn't depend on the border size?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have considered it but `box-shadow` has a default margin. Set it to 0 and you achieve the desired result.

```css
.box {
  position:relative;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
}

.box-shadow {
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  margin: 0;
}

.text {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box-shadow">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this different from the second example I provide as an alternative? Except from the `margin: 0` it looks (and seems to work) the same

Comment: Well, avoiding using negative values in margin and / or positioning you are not dependant on the other html objects, that might get modify by DOM manipulations, so this solution would be the cleanest from my point of view.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the center 100 x 100 area is the region, where text contents will be placed. Every content will be calculated based on margin, border and padding.

[image: Element Outlines]

Therefore, I dont see a solution without using the negative margins or inset box as you mentioned, which is some kind of fix to the original question.