# Text overlapping borders of container with display:table

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, webkit

Running tests for a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40178681/3695983), I found a *strange* behavior that differs from browser to browser. I have a box with a border and relative positioning, and inside it, I have some text absolute positioned on the top left of the container, and I want the text to "overlap" the border (so it is positioned taking into account the border).

[blonfu](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29118/posicionamiento-absoluto-desde-el-exterior-del-borde#comment46988_29118) suggested that I could set the container display to table and that would do the trick. Something like this:

```css
.box {
  position:relative;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
}

.box-bordered {
  border:25px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display:table;
}

.text {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box-bordered">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

The result of running the code above on in Internet Explorer or Firefox looks like what I want:

[image: Text overlapping border]

But the same code in Safari or Chrome (WebKit browsers?) looks different:

[image: Text not overlapping border]

Which one is representing it correctly? What should be the expected behavior/display?

Comment: This statement is found in the [W3C spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position-3/#box-offsets-trbl) and in my opinion it seems to point towards WebKit being correct - *For absolutely positioned elements whose containing block is based on a block-level element, this property is an offset from the **padding edge of that element.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an outer div. This is because the border is considered not part of the dom element. So the position absolute looks in the html container not including the border. Chrome is the one representing it correctly. Don't trust IE when it comes to CSS and HTML compliance.

https://jsfiddle.net/L3L6o8ew/1/

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="box box-bordered">
    <div class="text">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer{
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
}

.box-bordered {
  border:25px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display:table;
}

.text {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  color:white;
}
```

Comment: did you checked in FF? Text is not visible

Comment: oops. I forgot to change span back to div